# polyglossia & fontspec's script feature in 'setotherlanguage'

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, polyglossia, hebrew

My fonts are able to give the wanted output.
My fonts have both the Latin and Hebrew characteres, and even Greek needed.

Is there any other way in which I can have the result wanted?
Do I need the line:
`\newfontfamily\hebrew[Script=Hebrew]{Cardo}`
...and accordingly the:  `\hebrew{....}` in the body-text?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Cardo} %SBL BibLit; Linux Libertine O; Cardo
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrew[Script=Hebrew]{Cardo}

\begin{document}
This hebrew text is Gen.1:1 from BHS\\
\RL{בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים}\\   % result: misplaced vowels & diacritics
\hebrew{\RL{בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים}}\\  % result: right placed vowels & diacritics
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[...]{...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it’s necessary to activate `Script=Hebrew` because Cardo defines Hebrew mark (that’s everything that behaves like a diacritic) positioning only for Hebrew script.

Comment: would you mind explaining what do you mean when saying to activate Script=Hebrew? (I'm Using TexShop) Thanks!!
@georgd

Comment: I’m not so sure that “activate” is the correct english verb for what I mean. What I wanted to say is, that you need to declare the [Script=Hebrew] option in the font definition. Opentype features are always defined within a set of script/language. In Cardo, hebrew diacritics positioning is only defined within hebrew script/default language, that’s why you need that option. Other fonts define these positionings in default script/default language, then you don’t need that option.